# Phonegap/Cordova - media api - when play audio from URL, UI freeze a few seconds

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, cordova

After few days of investigation, i still got no luck on this issue, thanks in advance if you can help me out!

i am using cordova 3.3 to do my iOS app, one feature is to play an audio clip from a URL.

I am using cordova's offical media api, here is how i use it following their offical examples

var myMedia = new Media("http://123.com/xyz.mp3");
myMedia.play()

**here is the issue: when the play event is fired, the UI freeze a few seconds,**

I believe this is due to fetching a remote resource from http://123.com/xyz.mp3, when play a mp3 locally, there is no such issue.

the media api seems do not offer preload kinda function.

when loading the remote url mp3, it is using the same thread as the UI therefore it freeze until the loading task is done....

does anyone experience the similar problem? how should fix this issue?

Thank you very much for you time :)

Comment: How about constructing the Media objects in advance of playing them? E.g. during a "loading" screen when your app first starts or resumes. I had the same issue with HTML5 audio object and this resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

We're currently developing an app that streams some music and we had the exact same problem.

We decide to go with the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement). You can use it just like this

```
var myAudio = new Audio("http://123.com/xyz.mp3");
myAudio.play();
```

This doesn't freeze our UI while loading and I even think it loads a little bit faster.
And it's also working in the browser, which is nice for testing.

The down side is, that Android doesn't support the HTML5 Media API and has some general problems with the Audio Element as well (in some versions on some devices). So if you want to support Android you probably better use the Phonegap Media API there.

Comment: thank you very much Jonas! one more question, does html5 audio tag allow seek to seconds?

Comment: Yes, by changing its currentTime property, e.g. `myAudio.currentTime = 60`.

Comment: I used the above method. It works but audio stops when app is exited. How can I avoid this?